# How to install Windows 7 from DVD?

Tags: windows-7, uninstall

I installed Ubuntu 12.04 in my laptop. Now I want to remove Ubuntu and I install Windows 7.

But when I restart my system after keeping Windows 7 DVD it is not booting.

What should I do to get rid of this problem?

I have tried to modify many options, but none of them had worked out?

Comment: In case your system does not want to boot from a bootable CD/DVD this is the error of either the settings in your BIOS (did you select it as a boot device?) or it's a faulty disc. I think this has nothing to do with Ubuntu, apart from that you installed that in the past.

Comment: What are you calling 'alongside' is actually not alongside install. I consider it murder.

Answer (score -1):

You would have to install windows 7 first (So it can boot from MBR) Then Install ubuntu alongside windows. Wubi installer and I think there is a option to set a different partition to dual boot for ubuntu

Comment: @Jorav, if you want to help, read the question carefully. OP said he has problem that prevents system from booting using Windows 7 DVD.